# How to set a value(datefirst) in an SQL statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having a problem trying to SET DATEFIRST while running a query in C#.

First off this is the sql statement that works in SQL management studio.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
GO

CREATE VIEW [Tannery_Data_View2] AS
SELECT [week_day] = DATENAME(dw, Tannery_Values.date), [week_ending] = DATEADD(DAY, 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dbo.Tannery_Values.date), dbo.Tannery_Values.date), Tannery_Values.date, Tannery_Values.value, Variable_Titles.Variable, [Performance_Category] = Performance_Categories.Category, [Process_Category] = Process_Categories.Category
FROM Tannery_Values 
INNER JOIN Variable_Titles ON Tannery_Values.variableTitleID=Variable_Titles.VariableID
INNER JOIN Performance_Categories ON Tannery_Values.performanceCategoryID=Performance_Categories.CategoryID
INNER JOIN Process_Categories ON Tannery_Values.processCategoryID=Process_Categories.CategoryID
```

Here is my code to call it.

```
public void executeNonQuery(string insertString)
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = insertString;
            command.Connection = sqlConnection;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
```

The insert string is the above sql statement commented out into a string. It throws the error that the CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in the batch. I have subsequently tried seperating it out into two queries with with create view seperate from the set statement but it doesn't work either. My understanding is that executenonquery is not the right method to be using here as the computer forgets it has been set? However, i can't seem to find what I actually need to do.

I could run a stored procedure and call that if it is easier but I would like to know what it is I am doing wrong. Especially since I cannot easily find the answer so it would be good to have it up here for others.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `SET DATEFIRST` in a view.

Probably the easiest way is to generate it in your C# before running your view

```
cmd.CommandText = "SET DATEFIRST 1";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or the best way to achieve that is having a Date Table

[Creating a Date Table/Dimension](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you have creates a view after it sets the First Day of the Week to Monday. This doesn't make sense since the View won't retain the DATEFIRST setting when it's actually run.

Are you sure you don't want the DATEFIRST to be part of the view you are creating?

```
CREATE VIEW [Tannery_Data_View2] AS
SET DATEFIRST 1;
GO

SELECT [week_day] = DATENAME(dw, Tannery_Values.date), [week_ending] = DATEADD(DAY, 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dbo.Tannery_Values.date), dbo.Tannery_Values.date), Tannery_Values.date, Tannery_Values.value, Variable_Titles.Variable, [Performance_Category] = Performance_Categories.Category, [Process_Category] = Process_Categories.Category
FROM Tannery_Values 
INNER JOIN Variable_Titles ON Tannery_Values.variableTitleID=Variable_Titles.VariableID
INNER JOIN Performance_Categories ON Tannery_Values.performanceCategoryID=Performance_Categories.CategoryID
INNER JOIN Process_Categories ON Tannery_Values.processCategoryID=Process_Categories.CategoryID
```

Or do you not just want to run the query:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
GO

SELECT [week_day] = DATENAME(dw, Tannery_Values.date), [week_ending] = DATEADD(DAY, 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dbo.Tannery_Values.date), dbo.Tannery_Values.date), Tannery_Values.date, Tannery_Values.value, Variable_Titles.Variable, [Performance_Category] = Performance_Categories.Category, [Process_Category] = Process_Categories.Category
FROM Tannery_Values 
INNER JOIN Variable_Titles ON Tannery_Values.variableTitleID=Variable_Titles.VariableID
INNER JOIN Performance_Categories ON Tannery_Values.performanceCategoryID=Performance_Categories.CategoryID
INNER JOIN Process_Categories ON Tannery_Values.processCategoryID=Process_Categories.CategoryID
```

Update:

After further review, SQL Server doesn't allow the use of DATEFIRST in a View. I used Luther Miller's theory (http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/normalizing-first-day-week) for using @@DateFirst to calculate the week.

```
SELECT [week_day] = DATENAME(dw, Tannery_Values.date), 
    [week_ending] = DATEADD(DAY, 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ((@@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7) + 1), dbo.Tannery_Values.date), 
    Tannery_Values.date, Tannery_Values.value, Variable_Titles.Variable, 
    [Performance_Category] = Performance_Categories.Category, [Process_Category] = Process_Categories.Category
FROM Tannery_Values 
INNER JOIN Variable_Titles ON Tannery_Values.variableTitleID=Variable_Titles.VariableID
INNER JOIN Performance_Categories ON Tannery_Values.performanceCategoryID=Performance_Categories.CategoryID
INNER JOIN Process_Categories ON Tannery_Values.processCategoryID=Process_Categories.CategoryID
```

Comment: Still getting an error from the first one. It says incorrect syntax near the word set.

Comment: OK - so I was incorrect. There is some weird thing that says you can't use DATEFIRST in a View for no reason I could find.

Since you only need it for one calculation, I used Luhter Miller's throery (http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/normalizing-first-day-week) - see my edits above.