# How to make a datepart() function in a view accept Monday as the first day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

For a webapplication I created the following view:

```
alter view [dbo].[vwBookingData] 
as
    select concat(rtrim(ltrim(str(datepart(year, bookingdata.booking_datetime)))), '-', rtrim(ltrim(str(datepart(week, bookingdata.booking_datetime))))) as  WeekNumber, 
           bookingdata.booking_customerCode as ClientCode, customer.Name as ClientName, concat(bookingdata.booking_provider, concat('-', bookingdata.booking_system)) as ProviderCombo,
           bookingdata.segments_carrierCode as CarrierCode, bookingdata.booking_datetime as BookingDate, bookingdata.booking_bookingId, flgConfirmed, flgFailed
    from dbo.flights_bookingdata bookingdata
         inner join dbo.Customer on Customer.Number = bookingdata.booking_customerCode
```

My problem is 1 specific part of the used query:

```
datepart(week, bookingdata.booking_datetime)
```

I have noticed the datepart() appears to take a week starts on Sunday rather than on Monday, this breaks the overview the view is supposed to generate.

Is there a way I can fix this within the query itself?

Comment: Read [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) especially the `week and weekday datepart Arguments` section.

Comment: I did before asking my question. But how can I be certain DATEFIRST always has the right value? µ

Comment: You have to `set datefirst 1;` on the top for each query that want to have a different start day than the default of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try  (I was right first with 1 not 2)

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

At the top of your query

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;  -- The Default
Select *
      ,WeedDay=DateName(DW,RetVal)
      ,WeekNo=DatePart(WK,RetVal) 
 From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-14','DD',1)
```

[image]

While

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
Select *
      ,WeedDay=DateName(DW,RetVal)
      ,WeekNo=DatePart(WK,RetVal) 
 From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-14','DD',1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you mean 2, because 1 is Sunday.

Comment: Yes, but it's inside a view. How can I be certain it will always assume Monday as the first day of the week?

Comment: You certain it's 2, and not ?

Comment: Arguments
number | @number_var
Is an integer that indicates the first day of the week. It can be one of the following values.
Value First day of the week is
1 Monday
2 Tuesday
3 Wednesday
4 Thursday
5 Friday
6 Saturday
7 (default, U.S. English) Sunday

Comment: @JiggsJedi Nope, I was correct with 1.  Just for fun, see the updated answer with illustration

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks, I should have looked it up! I've literally NEVER used DATEFIRST. *facepalm*

Comment: @JiggsJedi I've used it only once before, and it was done under protest.

Comment: The change to the view gets rejected when I try this: "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vwBookingData, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 2]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'."

Comment: You can't set datefirst in the view... check here for a workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481133/how-to-set-a-valuedatefirst-in-an-sql-statement-in-c-sharp (see update to first answer for normalizing date)

Comment: @Fysicus correct.  I should have stated that clearly.  I did mention "at the top of your query".  JiggsJedi supplied the appropriate workaround.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using EF for all my dataqueries :)

Comment: @Fysicus I've only flirted with EF, so I can't say.  It's not elegant, but what about  a UDF to replace the native DatePart week function?  I can't imagine the logic being too complex.  Let me know if I can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you can’t use the `SET DATEFIRST` option I would simply subtract one day from the datetime when you call the `DATEPART` function as follow:

```
DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -1, bookingdata.booking_datetime))
```

Answer (score 0):

With this function you can return the day of the week, starting from monday, in any server language or DATEFIRST setting:

```sql
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Javier Cañon
-- Create date: 2019-04-23
-- Description: Return day of week without know of server SET DATEFIRST setting
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetWeekDayFromMonday]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @SomeDate DATE
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SqlWeekDay INT, @ResultVar int;

    SET  @SqlWeekDay= DATEPART(dw, @SomeDate);
    SET @ResultVar = ((@SqlWeekDay + @@DATEFIRST - 1 - 1) % 7) + 1;

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ResultVar;

END
GO
```